# Program class is catching exceptions that I've already caught

Tags: c#, try-catch

I am getting the error

> InvalidArgument=Value of '4' is not valid for 'index'.

on

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Intelletrace takes me up to this code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (dataBase.tagInclude.Count() == 0)
                {
                    commonTags.Add(dataBase.set.Tables["tagTable"].Select("tag like '*'", "count desc")[i]["tag"].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    commonTags.Add(dataBase.tagPruneList[i].tag);
                }
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                break;
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

With the error being on `catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)`

I don't understand why it is doing this if I am not throwing the exception. Also it only just started doing this but this code has worked for some time and I haven't changed it recently. When I code it so that it doesn't throw an error it just does the same thing with a different line of code that has worked even longer.

The code I added seems pretty harmless and unrelated:

```
    public static void itemChecked(ListViewItem lvi)
    {
        if (supressChecks) return;
        if (!lvi.Checked)
        {
            dataBase.Tag(lvi.Tag.ToString());
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

The only thing this code is doing differently is calling the dataBase.Tag() function with a listviewitem tag rather than a textbox.text.

Comment: "Also it only just started doing this but this code has worked for some time and I haven't changed it recently. " - You added or changed code to the application; that addition/change might be causing an unwanted side effect.  Put a breakpoint in the method you changed and step through the code to see if you can ascertain what is happening.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing but even after hundreds of stepintos I can't tell what the issue is, nothing unusual is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You are catching:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException
ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

But what is being thrown is:

```
 InvalidArgument
```

...according to the information in your post.   It looks like a function is expecting a number and you are passing in a char or string.  Catch the thrown exception.

Comment: The debugger says that InvalidArgument is being thrown by Application.Run and ArgumentOutOfRangeException is being thrown by that block of code. If I add a catch for InvalidArgument I just get an error, the compiler doesn't know what that is. Adding a catch for System.ArgumentException doesn't change anything.

Comment: You should edit your post to include the exact text of the exception and the precise line where the exception is thrown.